# From where can I download build symbols generated by VSTS Build?

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, hockeyapp

I included the [Index Sources and Publish Symbols task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=vsts) in my build pipeline and my build succeed.

In my build info, I can see that build symbols were generated, but I am not able to download those symbol files. Can you point me to the path from where can I download the build symbols?

[image]

**EDIT:**

Why I need build Symbols:

I have my build associated with the Hockey App and in order to get more refine details for the crash report I want to associate build symbols in the Hockey App.

What I tried:

I also tried to provide build symbol path in Hockey App agent but it didn't upload any symbol and the only build was uploaded.

Below are my VSTS build configurations:

**Publish Symbol Path**

[image]

Hockey App Agent:

[image]

After the help from Justin, I update my build agent and now my build Agent looks like this:

[image]

I can see the symbols in build artifact but the content in the folder seems to be a little weird, I can't figure out which PDB is for X86 and X64.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the instructions provided in the link you posted? What didn't work?

Comment: Yes, I went through that link but instead of using YAML as mentioned there I used Agent Job as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/symbols/?view=vsts)

Comment: Did you look at the link for "Consume symbols"?

Comment: What didn't work is that I am unable to download generated symbols.

Comment: **What** didn't work? Did you get an error message? You need to be as specific as possible when requesting help. No one except you knows what you've attempted, what resources you've already looked at, or what error messages you're receiving.

Comment: Actually I didn't got any error, but "Symbols_release" is not clickable, I can't download symbol files. While drop is clickable to download my build.

Comment: I didn't follow the article mentioned in that blog itself, but instead I referred this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/11/15/vsts-is-now-a-symbol-server/). Will go trough that article also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're publishing the symbols to the Build.SourcesDirectory, it's cut off in your picture. You need to publish to the Build. ArtifactStagingDirectory.

Also, if you need to take a peek at where things are on your agent you can add a task. For Windows agents I add a powershell task, select inline script, then do something like:

tree /F $(Agent.BuildDirectory)

Then check your logs for that task.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. Still, I am not able to download any symbols. Is there because it is unable to find symbols from BuildDirectory?

Comment: Can you use the tree method I described above to inspect your build agent's file system? If it is producing symbol files you should be able to locate them and move them to the artifact stating directory.

Comment: As you mentioned, I added the powershell task and in the logs, I can see that PDB was generated but am not sure what to do next. Could you please help me with that. You can view the generated log [here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AmazyQ-ydr33hIF4Kb-917Fu2p8gJg).

Comment: @Dishant I just realized you have the "Publish Symbols" option checked. That means Azure Devops will act as a symbol server. Check out this article to learn about that and how to consume. If you just want to publish the symbols to a drop folder then you'll need to uncheck that option.

Comment: I unchecked "Publish Symbols" options, but after the build I was not able to find any symbols inside a drop folder. Also, I can't find the link in your comment.

Comment: Thanks, I went through the blog post but actually I don't want to consume symbol from VSTS, what I need is just a .pdb files generated from VSTS build. I also tried creating copy task but with that also no symbols were copied.

Comment: Looking at your log we can confirm there are pdb files in your agent sources directory: "D:\A\1\s"  Confirm the following: 1) In your publish symbols path task, the "path to publish symbols" parameter should be set to something like "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\symbols". When you run the build, look at the logs for that task and make sure it is moving files. 2) use the tree command to confirm "tree /F $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)" 3) Following your publish symbols path task, you should have a Publish Artifact task, set Path to Publish to: "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I was using only 1 Publish Task and thought that it will take care of both build package and symbol files. Now I have created another Publish Task for symbols agent and after the build, I can see symbols in the artifact. Weird thing is that in the symbols folder there are multiple subfolders with PDB files and I am not able to figure out which PDB is for X64 or X86. Please see my update post.

Comment: Could you add an additional publish symbols step and change the search patterns to differentiate the platform? Example: 1) **\bin\\**\x86\\**\\*.pdb, 
2) **\bin\\**\x64\\**\\*.pdb

Comment: That's what I thought as a possible solution. But actually in Hockey App task I have to provide symbol file location and I am not sure if I publish x64 and x86 symbols to different folder location than what path should I provided in that field. Anyways that seems to be the different issue, I will create a new thread for this. I got what I intended for this thread(to download build symbols). I appreciate your help. Thank you. It would be better if you can update your answer with the points that you mentioned in the comment sections and will be happy to accept this as an answer.